# MarkLogic - 'Cannot Read Module' error while calling custom end point through REST API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version: 9.0.4

Getting below error while making a REST API call to custom end point.

> "message": "RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: fn.error(null, 'RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ', -- Invalid request:  reason: cannot read module /marklogic.rest.resource/customer-pref/assets/resource.sjs for extension customer-pref . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail."
>   }}

I verified that the module `/marklogic.rest.resource/customer-pref/assets/resource.sjs` is present in data-hub-modules database. Also, I am using admin credentials while making this call. Still getting the error.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the rest extension contain any further imports?

Comment: Could you please help me understand what you mean by further imports. I had a xdmp.httpGet call inside my custom javascript code, but I removed it just to test if that is causing the issue. I am still getting the same error. In the code, I am importing dhf.xqy as 'const dhf = require('/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy');'

Comment: Yes, that. Does `/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy` exist in the datahub modules db as well?

Comment: /com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy exists in data-hub-MODULES db. How ever, I manually inserted the code. Basically, what happened was that I first ran mlundeploy command which cleared all DBs and App servers, then I ran mldeploy which created the data hub DBs and app servers but failed to complete (probably because ports 8010 and 8011 are ssl enabled). Then I tried mlLoadModules which complained that /com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy is not found. I manually inserted the code (copied from a different server) and mlLoadModules was successful. Is there a cleaner way to approach? Please suggest.

Comment: This is probably more suited for a github ticket as well: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/issues, but to give you something now: consider turning off ssl on 8010, and 8011 to make mldeploy happy, and then copy those app servers to new ones on different ports with ssl enabled. You can use firewall and such to hide 8010 and 8011 from outside..

Comment: Undeployed and Redeployed MarkLogic 9.0.4 using DHF 2.0.3 and that resolved the issue. Apparently DHF 3.0.0 works only for MarkLogic 9.0.5 or higher.

Comment: @Bhanu If that resolved your issue, put the explanation from your comment in as an answer and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undeployed and Redeployed MarkLogic 9.0.4 using DHF 2.0.3 and that resolved the issue. Apparently DHF 3.0.0 works only for MarkLogic 9.0.5 or higher.